# Why does this scrips falls into a loop when I source it?

Tags: bash

Why does this scrips falls into a loop when I source it (e.g. `. cd.sh file:///home/user/pCloudDrive/courses/CCNA/CCNA_200-301_Official_Cert_Guide/Odom,_Wendell_-_CCNA_200-301_Official_Cert_Guide,_Volume_1.pdf`)?

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

#alias cd='. ~/CS/SoftwareDevelopment/MySoftware/Bash/cd/cd.sh
#when I do cd file:///home/user/pCloudDrive/courses/CCNA/CCNA_200-301_Official_Cert_Guide/Odom,_Wendell_-_CCNA_200-301_Official_Cert_Guide,_Volume_1.pdf
#it is supposed to do cd /home/user/pCloudDrive/courses/CCNA/CCNA_200-301_Official_Cert_Guide

dst_dr=$(echo "${1}"|sed -E 's,file://,,;s,/[^/]*\.pdf|/[^/]*\.PDF,,')
echo "$dst_dr" 
export dst_dr
cd "$dst_dr"
```

The script outputs and does not stop:

```
/home/user/pCloudDrive/courses/CCNA/CCNA_200-301_Official_Cert_Guide
/home/user/pCloudDrive/courses/CCNA/CCNA_200-301_Official_Cert_Guide
/home/user/pCloudDrive/courses/CCNA/CCNA_200-301_Official_Cert_Guide
/home/user/pCloudDrive/courses/CCNA/CCNA_200-301_Official_Cert_Guide
```

I wrote it because frequently I have the need to cd to a directory of a pdf that I currently reading in my browser. The script is meant to give me the directory of such a pdf and cd to it.

Comment: Doesn't happen on my box. Do you have any other aliases active, e.g. for `sed` or `echo`?

Comment: `alias cd='. ~/CS/SoftwareDevelopment/MySoftware/Bash/cd/cd.sh` why would you do that? What do you think happens on `cd $dst_dr`?

Comment: @choroba I added two more lines to the script, now it loops. the line that exports seems to be the culprit.

Comment: @KamilCuk I modified my question with response to your comment.

Comment: Run your script with `set -x` turned on, and show the output.  Also (for the safe side) do a `type echo sed cd` before assigning to `dst_dr`.

Comment: Even after you comment out the line, that doesn't undo the alias in the shell you already sourced the old version of the script into; you need to `unalias cd` to do that

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : Or better start a fresh shell. Actually, writing a stand-alone "script" which requires to be sourced, sounds fishy to me. I would put the whole logic into a function, and define the function inside one of the bash startup files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does this scrips falls into a loop

You aliased `cd` to sourcing the script.

When you execute `cd`, the script is sourced.

The script executes `cd`.

Which in turn sources the script again.

And the script executes `cd` again.

Which sources the script again.

Which loops.

You can prefix the command with slash to execute without alias. You can use `\cd` in your script to execute real `cd` builtin.

You can prefix the command with `command` to execute the real command or builtin, not an alias nor function. You can use `command cd` in your script.

Aliasing `cd` sounds confusing, and aliasing to sourcing sounds more confusing. I recommend using a function. I recommend naming the function (and alias) something unique, like `mycd` or `cdmy`, and leave poor `cd` as it is.

Comment: At least in the posting after editing, there is no `alias` for cd; it is commented out. Of course since the OP is **sourcing** the script initially, it could be that the sourcing shell still has the alias defined. That's why in my comment, I suggested to do a `type cd` to make sure that such silly alias does not exist anymore.